# How to limit the functionalities of a bluetooth-connected headset?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, voice

I connect my Jabra headset to my Windows 10 via Bluetooth - without any problems.

The capabilities that are used by Windows 10 are music and voice. I would like to limit this to only music - is that possible?

On my Android phone I have the ability to "edit" a BT connection and select the features I want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the 'classic' Sound control panel dialog. Assuming your Jabra device is listed twice; from here, right-click and select Disable on Headset for your device.

[image]

This will prevent the system from using the headset as a hands-free device. As you can see, I have this working for my AKG headphones, which have a built-in mic.